# Selenium cannot find element in Smaller Screen resolution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a element with data-qa-id = "journal-submit";
When I ran the test with small screen resolution Selenium says this element is not visible and cannot perform any action on it. 
The same element is visible to selenium in regular chrome resolution. Can anyone explain me why it is so ? How to handle it ?

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options for solutions here. I think scrolling to an element can be a bit hacky, because then it will remove other elements from the view of the browser, so you'll end up having to scroll all over the place to locate elements that may or may not be in view of the browser.

But, if you wish to use a scrolling solution, you can try something like this:

```
// declare JS executor
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

// this is the element you want to find
WebElement element = driver.findElement(someLocatorHere);

// scroll to the element
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

I'm not a huge fan of this solution, for reasons I mentioned above. A "true" solution that will solve all problems of this type is to run your browser in `headless` and specify the screen size in the driver settings.

```
// declaring the webdriver

// headless options
ChromeOptions headlessOptions = new ChromeOptions();
headlessOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
headlessOptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
headlessOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1200");

// start driver
driver = new ChromeDriver(headlessOptions);
```

I prefer the headless solution because it will solve most, if not all, of your issues regarding smaller screen resolution. I've gone back and forth with screen resolution issues for the majority of my career, and scrolling all over pages to locate individual elements was not a long-term or robust solution. I had much better success using headless, and driver is able to locate all of my elements.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Feel free to accept this post as the answer to your question so other users can see that it worked for you.

Comment: AFAIK it won't work on chrome and server system/iis account since max resolution for non-user accounts is 1024x768 and chrome doesnt let you set window-size larger than system resolution

Comment: Can always adjust window size parameter to meet those needs - if users still experience screen size issues with 1024x768 then issue should probably be taken up with UI developers to work on their scaling.

Answer (score 1):

I used JavascriptExecutor and it worked

`JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)browser;
WebElement submit_btn = browser.findElement(By.name("submit-btn"));
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",submit_btn);`

Answer (score 0):

If selenium not able to identify web element due to resolution then try to move to the element using action.

```
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))   
.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someid")));
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
```

Then perform required action on the webelement